# merge 2 selects into 1

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select

im working on a select.
I've got a table called vriend and a table called gebruiker. now i got 2 select that give me the result i want but i want to merge them together

```
SELECT g.naam,g.gebruikerID 
FROM gebruiker g 
INNER JOIN vriend v on g.gebruikerID = v.gebruikerID_Jezelf 
WHERE g.gebruikerID IN(SELECT gebruikerID_Jezelf FROM vriend);

SELECT g.naam,g.gebruikerID 
FROM gebruiker g 
INNER JOIN vriend v on g.gebruikerID = v.gebruikerID_Persoon 
WHERE g.gebruikerID IN(SELECT gebruikerID_Persoon FROM vriend);
```

what i want is to merge those 2 sleect statements together **NOT WITH A UNION** but for example:

select 1 gives:

```
NAAM     |     ID
-----------------
Henk     |     1
Karel    |     2
```

Select 2 gives :

```
NAAM     |     ID
-----------------
Andrew   |     4
Piet     |     5
```

The merge would be than

```
NAAM     |     ID     | NAAM     |     ID
------------------------------------------
Henk     |     1      | Andrew   |     4
Karel    |     2      | Piet     |     5
```

Comment: The WHERE clauses make no sense, they only duplicate the condition in the JOIN...ON condition, so they are always true, and you can omit them.

Comment: well that is true that the where is makig no sense but still how can i merge them or do you know a better select statement for this because the problem is that the name of the people is standing in the gebruiker table and only the ID in the vriend table.
what i want is not only showing the ID but also the name of that user.

Comment: The solution by @user2919513 looks correct (but he could omit the entire where clause)

Comment: Why is Henk related to Andrew? Why is Karel related to Piet?  I don't see the relationship in your data.  What does "merge" mean?  It usually means UNION, but you have ruled that out.

Comment: in the table vriend is standing who is friend with who for example Henk (ID 1) is friends with Andrew(ID4) but the ID is inserted into the table vriend what i want to show is the ID AND the name.
and the name is from the table gebruiker

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you just add the contents of gebruiker (at least 4 rows)  and vriend (at least 2 rows) to the question. (I still have the feeling that this is a directed graph, and the vriend table contains the edges)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT g.naam,g.gebruikerID ,g2.naam,g2.gebruikerID
FROM gebruiker g , gebruiker g2, vriend v
WHERE g.gebruikerID = v.gebruikerID_Jezelf 
OR g2.gebruikerID = v.gebruikerID_Persoon
AND g.gebruikerID IN(SELECT gebruikerID_Jezelf FROM vriend) 
OR g2.gebruikerID IN(SELECT gebruikerID_Persoon FROM vriend);
```

Comment: Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "G"."GEBRUIKERID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier" this error is on the first inner join

Comment: it is almost working but i will get double rows like for example piet is friend with hisself

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT g.naam, g.gebruikerID
    , g2.naam, g2.gebruikerID
FROM vriend v
JOIN gebruiker g1 on g1.gebruikerID = v.gebruikerID_Jezelf 
JOIN gebruiker g2 ON g2.gebruikerID = v.gebruikerID_Persoon
   ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT g.naam,g.gebruikerID 
   FROM gebruiker g 
   INNER JOIN vriend v on g.gebruikerID = v.gebruikerID_Jezelf 
   WHERE g.gebruikerID IN(SELECT gebruikerID_Jezelf FROM vriend) OR g.gebruikerID IN(SELECT  gebruikerID_Persoon FROM vriend);
```